# What is the fastest known algorithm for building this string depending on input number?

Tags: php, algorithm, time-complexity

To set up a folder structure dependant on the identifier of an entry in some database (which is an integer greater than zero), I need a function that will break it by digits, and build a string of forward slashes and upper and lower bounds depending on a number's position.

To see an example of how a string should look like, take a number n = 123456. After applying the algorithm, the following string should be produced:

**100000-199999/20000-29999/3000-3999/400-499/50-59/6/**

If the same algorithm is applied to number n = 1234567890, then it will produce the following string:

**1234500000-1234599999/60000-69999/7000-7999/800-899/90-99/0/**

Which means it should stop splitting the number after hundreds of thousands, thus it must have a limit of *exactly 6 forward slashes*.

I've got the following basis of the algorithm, which I assume is a naive solution and can be improved way much:

```
<?php

function produceString(int $n) {
    $ranges = array();
    $k = strlen(strval($n)) - 1;
    while ($k >= 0) {
        $a = floor($n / pow(10, $k)) * pow(10, $k);
        $b = $a + pow(10, $k) - 1;
        array_push($ranges, $a == $b ? "$a" : "$a-$b");
        $n = $n % pow(10, $k);
        $k -= 1;
    }
    return implode("/", $ranges);
}
```

As the iterations of `while` loop depend on the number of digits of n, I dare say this algorithm has the complexity **O(n)**.

Two questions about it that I have is how do I limit it to the maximum of 6 forward slashes, and how to reduce its complexity to, for example, **O(log(n))**.

Comment: _"how do I limit it to the maximum of 6 forward slashes"_ - by making your "pow factor" not go above 5 -  `$k = min(strlen(strval($n)) - 1, 5);`

Comment: While you have a limit of 6 levels, you are about to get O(6) by picking digits from the end of your number. I'm not sure if it is possible to make this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output generated by **your** code is not O() in size, you cannot hope to even do this with a O() time complexity.

Even if we ignore the punctuation characters (`-` and `/`), the output consists of:

- digits +  digits
- −1 digits + −1 digits
- −2 digits + −2 digits
- ...
- 2 digits + 2 digits
- 1 digit

So the total number of digits in the output is one less than 2∑<sub><sub>=1..</sub></sub>, which is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and thus the number of characters in the output is O(²).

As your algorithm has to produce each character in that output, it has a time complexity of at least O(²). Inspecting your code, its time complexity is not worse than that, so O(²).

Remark: your desired output has a slash at the end, but your code does not produce it -- `implode` will only add the separator between the chunks. So if you really need that final slash, you'll need to add it. For instance:

```
return implode("/", $ranges) . "/";
```

Secondly, if you limit the number of generated chunks to 6, then the time complexity will fall back to O(), as now only the size of the left-most chunk is variable. The size of the 5 other chunks is limited by a constant, and thus not relevant. See last section in my answer on implementing this limit.

### Ideas for improvement

Although you cannot improve the time complexity, there are still some tiny improvements you could apply:

- Avoid floating point calculations -- so no `/` operator, and no `pow()` calls.
- Skip the array; as the involved strings are not large, it is a bit faster if you just concatenate to a string variable immediately.
- Avoid the check for the final digit (with the ternary expression). Instead deal with this case separately, outside of the loop.

Here is how that could be done:

```
function produceString(int $n) {
    $power = 10;
    $res = (string)$n % 10; // Collect final digit separately
    $n = intdiv($n, 10);
    while ($n > 0) {
        $low = $n % 10 * $power;
        $high = $low + $power - 1;
        $n = intdiv($n, 10);
        $res = "$low-$high/$res";
        $power *= 10; 
    }
    return $res;
}
```

#### Timing

On https://3v4l.org/ I executed the following:

```
for ($n = 123400000; $n < 123600000; $n++) produceString($n);
```

Execution times:

- With your code: 830ms
- With my code: 240ms

## Limiting the number of chunks to 6

In that case we can add a loop condition so that we break out of it when the fifth iteration is made (excluding the work for the right-most chunk which is done before the loop starts), and deal with prefixing the remaining digits:

```
function produceString(int $n) {
    $power = 10;
    $res = (string)$n % 10;
    $n = intdiv($n, 10);
    while ($n > 0) {
        $low = $n % 10 * $power;
        $high = $low + $power - 1;
        $n = intdiv($n, 10);
        if ($power >= 100000) {
            return $n ? "$n$low-$n$high/$res" : "$low-$high/$res";
        }
        $res = "$low-$high/$res";
        $power *= 10; 
    }
    return $res;
}
```